# Copy missed data from top/bottom row col values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `dataframe`, with index, category and few other columns. index and category never be empty/null. but other columns data comes null, When all other columns data is null then we have to copy from top/bottom row values based on cateogry.

```
val df = Seq(
  (1,1, null, null, null ), 
  (2,1, null, null, null ), 
  (3,1, null, null, null ), 
  (4,1,"123.12", "124.52", "95.98" ), 
  (5,1, "452.12", "478.65", "1865.12" ), 
  (1,2,"2014.21", "147", "265"), 
  (2,2, "1457", "12483.00", "215.21"), 
  (3,2, null, null, null),
  (4,2, null, null, null) ).toDF("index", "category", "col1", "col2", "col3")


scala> df.show
+-----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|index|category|   col1|    col2|   col3|
+-----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|    1|       1|   null|    null|   null|
|    2|       1|   null|    null|   null|
|    3|       1|   null|    null|   null|
|    4|       1| 123.12|  124.52|  95.98|
|    5|       1| 452.12|  478.65|1865.12|
|    1|       2|2014.21|     147|    265|
|    2|       2|   1457|12483.00| 215.21|
|    3|       2|   null|    null|   null|
|    4|       2|   null|    null|   null|
+-----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Expecting `dataframe` as below

```
+-----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|index|category|   col1|    col2|   col3|
+-----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|    1|       1| 123.12|  124.52|  95.98|       // Copied from below for same category
|    2|       1| 123.12|  124.52|  95.98|       // Copied from below for same category
|    3|       1| 123.12|  124.52|  95.98|
|    4|       1| 123.12|  124.52|  95.98|
|    5|       1| 452.12|  478.65|1865.12|
|    1|       2|2014.21|     147|    265|
|    2|       2|   1457|12483.00| 215.21|
|    3|       2|   1457|12483.00| 215.21|       // Copied from above for same category
|    4|       2|   1457|12483.00| 215.21|       // Copied from above for same category
+-----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: using `spark` 2.1.0.2.6.0.3-8 version  and `Scala` 2.11 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** When several rows with nulls possible, advanced Windows have to be used:

```
val cols = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3")
val beforeWindow = Window
  .partitionBy("category")
  .orderBy("index")
  .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

val afterWindow = Window
  .partitionBy("category")
  .orderBy("index")
  .rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)

val result = cols.foldLeft(df)((updated, columnName) =>
  updated.withColumn(columnName,
    coalesce(col(columnName),
      last(columnName, ignoreNulls = true).over(beforeWindow),
      first(columnName, ignoreNulls = true).over(afterWindow)
    ))
)
```

In one null case can be resolved with Window functions "lead" and "lag", and "coalesce":

```
val cols = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3")
val categoryWindow = Window.partitionBy("category").orderBy("index")

val result = cols.foldLeft(df)((updated, columnName) =>
  updated.withColumn(columnName,
    coalesce(col(columnName),
      lag(col(columnName), 1).over(categoryWindow),
      lead(col(columnName), 1).over(categoryWindow)
    ))
)
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|index|category|col1   |col2    |col3   |
+-----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|1    |1       |123.12 |124.52  |95.98  |
|2    |1       |123.12 |124.52  |95.98  |
|3    |1       |452.12 |478.65  |1865.12|
|1    |2       |2014.21|147     |265    |
|2    |2       |1457   |12483.00|215.21 |
|3    |2       |1.25   |3.45    |26.3   |
|4    |2       |1.25   |3.45    |26.3   |
+-----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: had more consecutive rows as null for col1, col2, col3 some cases. for this kind of scenario above logic is not working. updated the question with consecutive null rows

Comment: updated with solution for several nulls, please take a look.